# Combining multiple optional variables in .htaccess rewrites

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Trying to handle multiple potential re-writes in one .htaccess

each subdomain should resolve to a folder
each /a/username should resolve to /?a=username

I have each rule working on their own.  But I cannot figure out how to get them both working at the same time.

---

examples (working now):

- www.domain.com -> no change
- black.domain.com -> www.domain.com/black (works)
- white.domain.com -> www.domain.com/white (works)
- www.domain.com/a/username -> www.domain.com/?a=username  (works)

---

What I need to get working:

- white.domain.com/a/username -> www.domain.com/white/?a=username (fails - becomes only www.domain.com/white)
- black.domain.com/a/username -> www.domain.com/black/?a=username (fails - becomes only www.domain.com/black)

---

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php?$ / [NC,R,L]

#RewriteRule ^(.*).domain.com$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [QSA,R=302,L]

RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" !^www.* [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" !^admin.* [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" !^mail.* [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" !^email.* [NC]

RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" ^([^\.]+).domain.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/%1 [R=302] 

RewriteRule ^a/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/%1?a=$1 [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your rules to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php?$ / [NC,R,L]

#RewriteRule ^(.*).domain.com$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [QSA,R=302,L]

RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" !^www.* [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" !^admin.* [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" !^mail.* [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" !^email.* [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" ^([^\.]+).domain.*$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/%1 [R=302] 

RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" !^www.* [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" !^admin.* [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" !^mail.* [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" !^email.* [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" ^([^\.]+).domain.*$
RewriteRule ^a/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/%1?a=$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: This does not work: www.domain.com/a/username -> www.domain.com/?a=username  so I added..

Comment: RewriteRule ^a/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/%1?a=$1 [R=302,L]  after your version and it all works